# Fragment contents to enterPictureInPictureMode()

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-8.0-oreo

As its understood that, since from Android 8.0 (API level 26) it allows activities to launch in picture-in-picture (PIP) mode.

Is there any way to enterPictureInPicture contents of fragments only.

It works good with normal activities, but not sure how to handle for fragment contents.

I have surfaceview in fragment , which i would like to enter into inbuilt feature of PIP.

Answer (score 3):

For PIP you need something that has it's own `Window` to draw in, `Fragment`s don't have this; they're basically `View`s with lifecycle support and backstack / navigation functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Let it be any fragment it has to be part of the activity. You can make it work indirectly by hiding away all other UI elements in `onPictureInPictureModeChanged` leaving it only with the content of your fragment. 
There is no Direct support to show the only fragment contents.